# my cube browser doesnt show the measures?

Tags: ssas, etl, cube

I have performed ETL operation and i created a data warehouse and i loaded the data to it and so far its fine.. my ETL seems to work allright since my data warehouse contains all the data i needed. And then i created an SSAS project from my data warehouse following the AdventureWorks DW example. I deployed the cube and processed it. Then i tried to browse the cube. But here is a problem, it seems as the members do exist but the measures are empty. because my dimensions contain the data but when i throw the measures to it .. it is just gonna be empty cells. What causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cube designer, check the "Dimension Usage" tab. Make sure that the intersection between a dimension and a measure group has something there (If there's meant to be a relation).

What happens if you drag & drop the measure to the browser, without any dimensions?

Also what version of SSAS are you on, is it 2005? That had IgnoreUnrelatedDimensions set differently to 2008 I think..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've linked your dimensions with measure groups (i.e. that you fact table references you dimension tables).

Also make sure you have foreign keys defined in your data warehouse (as soon as wizards in Visual Studio use them when proposing cube structure).

Comment: actually my fact table does include foreign keys referencing the primary key from all my dimension tables. But when i deploy the cube only the dimension will contain data but not the measures.

Comment: Did you analyze processing log? SSAS shows all the queries it executes and a lot of additional info (like processing times). This might help you determine what's going on.

Comment: can you please give me a hint how i analyze the logs. because the biggest problem is i have no idea what got executed and what didnt.. and i am new to this technology.. is there a quick way to do this log analysis?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy to a different dwh server

Right Click on the CubeNAME

Go to properties

In Configuration properties > Go to Deployment

In Processing option - change Default to - Do not Process.

if in case the DB is very large and keep huge data, it will get deployed and you can process it later.

For Target - Set name of Server

Click on OK, Deploy and later process